# Detecting node-webkit during npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-webkit

I'm working on a library for node.js that is build primarily as a native module. As such, when people try to include it in node-webkit projects, they have to recompile it using `nw-gyp` instead of `node-gyp`. I know we can detect node-webkit specifically when our built code runs using something like this:

`try {
        isNodeWebkit = (typeof require('nw.gui') !== "undefined");
    } catch(e) {
        isNodeWebkit = false;
    }`

However, I would like to detect this inside of our install script (run by `npm install`). Alternatively, we look in our own `package.json`, but is there maybe a way to look at the root project's `package.json`? That way we could at least look at some property, maybe `engine` or something?

Comment: But there is no sign that engine is node-webkit in there.  Perhaps you could parse package.json to find root index file, then parse the .js scripts mentioned in that index file and see if nw,gui is referred to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a module to do this: https://github.com/maxkorp/which-native-nodish (also supports atom-shell and the renamed nw.js)

The gist is that you start at the parent directory to the module, and keep going up as long as you are a child of a node_modules folder which is a child of a folder with a package.json. Once at the root level, check the engines property in the package.json for an atom-shell, node-webkit or nwjs property. Not guaranteed to work (The farthest ancestor project must specify if its using a node-ish engine in this way), but it's better than nothing, and the only out of the box solution I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

In order to look into your own package.json you can do something like this

```
gui = require(nw.gui); 
myPackageJSONFile = gui.App.manifest; // this will get the package.json file
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply as this:

```
isNodeWebkit = (typeof process == "object");
```